# Automating program opening and workspace switching

Tags: linux, fedora, raspberry-pi3

I have a Raspberry PI 3 running Fedora 21 with MATE. It is to be used to simply autoload firefox to a specific website and display some useful statistics from that page.

The tricky part is I have two different sections of that page that I need to see. I was able to get firefox to auto-start two different profiles and with the help of Greasemonkey it goes to the correct section of the pages needed. I now nee to be able to open both windows in fullscreen on two different workspaces at startup. Then I need the workspaces to autoswap like every 30 seconds. This will be on a TV overhead with the only access being SSh which is why it needs to be automated. This is beyond my knowledge now.

I have tried to use Compiz Rotate Cubes and Desktop Cubes, but I cant automate this. At this point I am at a loss.

EDIT: I have managed through a custom script to get Firefox in two profiles on two workspaces!!!! Still trying to get the desktop to switch.

Answer (score 0):

I have actually solved this by writing two scripts
The first script switches workspaces 30 seconds after boot and opens the second Mozilla browser with a second profile.

Basically

```
#! /bin/bash
sleep 30 &&
wmctrl -s 1
firefox -P Profile2 -no-remote
sleep 15
wmctrl -s 0
```

The second script is an infinite while do:

```
while:;
do
sleep 30
wmctrl -s 1
sleep 30
wmctrl -s 0
done
```

I'm sure there are better ways to accomplish this, but this seems to work for us.